# Why in some files require /app/ works, in others doesn't?

Tags: php

In some files `require '/app/'` works, in some doesn't, but require `'app/'` works in those pages where `'/app/'` breaks. Why is that? I can't use `__DIR__`, because it can't load .css files then

Comment: Why doesnt it work? What error messages do you see? Does the folder exists?

Comment: i never knew PHP can require a folder...

Comment: hey, then mind to throw in more description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's because there are 2 types of Unix path's:

absolute path: `/app/` (always begins with `/`)

relative path: `app/` (relative to the place where you are. has no `/` in the beginning)

Imagine that you are in `/var/www`

If you use `/app/` (abosolute) - you talk about `/app/` folder

If you use `app/` (relative to the palce where you are) - you talk about `/var/www/app/`. It means that you want to use directory "app" in `/var/www/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

The following syntax should always work (PHP 4+):

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/otherFile.php');
```

Where `otherFile.php` is in the same folder where the current file is stored in. You then can navigate forward and backward (=> `/../`) from there.

`__DIR__` probably doesn't work, because it is PHP 5.3+.